# I get error: Trying to get property 'product' of non-object when I remove an object from my cart

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-query-builder

This is my controller,I tried to change using

```
if(Count( $newcart[products]) > 0)
```

instead of

```
if(Count( $newcart->products) > 0)
```

but it didn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1kNF.png)

Comment: you need to get $product again (after you delete an item from it)

Comment: @AliSafaei Can you explain or correct where I am wrong?

Comment: it's completely tricky . i suggest before your "if" do dd($newcart) to see what we got here. i'm around if you can test... ill answer soon

Comment: it returns me "null"

Comment: that's the problem . you must get your cart again (right before your "if" ). idk how your cart codes works .

Comment: anytime. hope it solved.

Comment: You should never use images for code. Add code as formatted text to your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
dd($newcart->products);
```

if you get null so

```
dd($newcart);
```

and see if it contains products

Answer (score 0):

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $items = session('cart');
    foreach ($items as $key => $date)
    {
        if ($date['id'] == $id)
        {
          unset($items [$key]);
        }
    }
    $request->session()->push('cart',$items);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Hope you can get idea from here and it helps you.